# The transparent box doesnt take color in css

Tags: html, css

I have an image behind a text box in html css. I want this textbox to be transparent but to have some color. Everything is ok but the transbox dont seem to be colored except for black and white. This is my html code:

```css
.background {
  background: url(../images/background.png) repeat;
  border: 2px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  filter: sepia(100%);
}
.transbox {
  margin: 30px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.transbox p {
  margin: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">

  <div class="transbox">
    <p>IMPORTANTE COMUNICAZIONE</p>
    <p>Nei mesi di Luglio ed Agosto operatività ridotta per avvicendamento ferie. Vi possono essere ritardi nelle spedizioni. Saremo chiusi dal 10 al 19 Agosto. Potete inviare i vostri ordini che saranno evasi dal 23 Agosto. Non dimenticate di indicare le
      date in cui sarete assenti per ferie od altro. Grazie.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result is this:
[image]
So Icant see the background colored in red.
Is something I shopuld change in my code or the transboxes cant take other colors exceopt black,white and grey. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that your example working fine.

Comment: yup. it is working fine

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Yep it works but the background isnt red. Is it?

Comment: Yes, the background is red. https://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/7aq5r8gb/1/

Comment: maybe share more of your code. something is interfering . do you have some greyscale or something like that ?

Comment: Yes I have an image in background

Comment: well. you have `filter:grayscale(100%)` on a div that contains also the img and also the `.transbox` ?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: I don't see 'red' in your code. I do see 'sepia', and that matches the image you posted...

Comment: do you want sepia in background css

Comment: @Doe that `sepia(100%)` on the `.background` is causing this. see my answer below

Comment: Where you set 'background:red;'?

Comment: @MadalinaTaina he is setting `background-color:red` on `.transbox` which is `child` of `.background` that has `filter:sepia(100%)` which is causing the problem

Comment: @MihaiT He edited the question now. I supposed that too, after I review the first version of the code, but when you answered, he didn't have that line. It was backgrouns:#fff; tghere because I copied the code in a jsfiddle. I agree your answer is correct, his question was not ok.

Comment: @MihaiT I upvoted the answer, I agree it is ok.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina yep. he didn't provide all the code. we had to guess what was going wrong :) thanks for the vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you have `filter:sepia(100%)` on `.background` which is `parent` of `.transbox` , the `transbox` inherits the `filter`  and that's why your color is either black or white and not other colors.

one solution would be to use a `:before` pseudo-element on `.background` and add the `background-img` and `filter:sepia(100%)` to that pseudo-element instead on the `.background`

see code snippet below. let me know if it helps

```css
.background {
 
  border: 2px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;

}
.transbox {
  margin: 30px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.transbox p {
  margin: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
.background:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico) repeat;
    opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  filter: sepia(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">

  <div class="transbox">
    <p>IMPORTANTE COMUNICAZIONE</p>
    <p>Nei mesi di Luglio ed Agosto operatività ridotta per avvicendamento ferie. Vi possono essere ritardi nelle spedizioni. Saremo chiusi dal 10 al 19 Agosto. Potete inviare i vostri ordini che saranno evasi dal 23 Agosto. Non dimenticate di indicare le
      date in cui sarete assenti per ferie od altro. Grazie.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately only a wrapper. Check this...

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 92vw;
  height: 6em;
  margin: 10px 4vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url(http://beerhold.it/400/300);
  background-size: cover;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.transbox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
}
.transbox p {
  margin: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="transbox">
    <p>IMPORTANTE COMUNICAZIONE</p>
    <p>Grazie.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```